# Flutter ver. 2.8.1 setState value

Tags: flutter, dart

im using flutter 2.8.1, so the idea is im using Radio widget with stateful then when i try to change the groupValue of the Radio widget with the new value / onChanged:(value) it tells this

the value has red underline

```
Object? value
A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'int'.
```

code

```
int radioValue = 0;

                   Radio(
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                      value: index,
                      groupValue: radioValue,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        print(e['value']);
                        setState(() {
                          radioValue = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
Radio<int>(
          value: radioValue,
          groupValue: 2,
          onChanged: (v) {
            setState(() {
              radioValue = v!;
            });
          },
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

change Radio to `Radio<int>` and the value to `value!`